# Temporary Power Generator Connect

Tags: electrical, generator

Post-hurricane: if one wanted to correctly restore power to electric circuits with a generator, what should one consider when connecting the generator to circuitry?

- Disconnect circuit from power company
- Ensure all paths are rated for current drawn

I do not intend to drive high current devices like the heatpump, stove, microwave, etc.  Lights, boxfans, cellphones.

Comment: Making sure that some knave *can't* accidentally connect your generator to the power grid?

Comment: A more permanent solution, would be to install a transfer switch and generator inlet. For a quick solution, extension cords plugged into the generator will get you up and running.

Comment: Unless this is life-critical, I   ***very*** strongly recommend a transfer switch. Not having one poses a risk to other lives.

Comment: If you do not purchase a transfer switch a breaker lockout device would be a good idea. Like this [they screw on then close](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/tools/safety-locking-devices/safety-lockout-and-hasps/master-lock-grip-tight-circuit-breaker-lockout-fits-standard-height-tie-bar-toggles?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CPzi_evhyM8CFYlbfgodUYoHMQ). that way no one can accidentally turn the breaker on.

Comment: Do **NOT** do anything until you've read the User's Manual completely and are absolutely sure you understand it (and understand the dangers related to 120 or 240 VAC power lines)

Comment: I should also note that a standard generator typically will not power electrical devices very well. You'll need an invertor generator for that.